# Where can i find the community builder mail function?

Tags: email, joomla

I want to have an customize email after the registration in my community builder, I want to do it in the main mailing function of community builder.

Where could I find that certain function/file?

or any Idea how to customize community builder mailing function, I want it to be in HTML based and have some pictures and graphics on it.,

Tnx for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the function `comprofilerMail` which is in the file administrator/components/com_comprofiler/comprofiler.class.php

Comment: I couldn't find that function in my comprofiler.class.php.., in what line could i find it?..,